# how to disable timestamp in WCF "wsHTTPBinding"?

Tags: wpf, wcf, xaml

I want to disable timestamp in WCF wsHTTPBinding because if I have client has different time more than 10 min it give me exception that the time is in the future how I can disable it or if there is another solution ?
code example in client :in app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IFileTransferServiceClient" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                            algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/filetransfer/FileTransferServiceClient/"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IFileTransferServiceClient"
                contract="IFileTransferServiceClient" name="WSHttpBinding_IFileTransferServiceClient">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post the exact exception message.

Comment: Maybe you should fix the time diff?

Comment: @John: If I'm the author of a service, it's pretty unlikely that I have control over the clock of the clients' PCs!

Comment: Depends on whether you work for the same organization as the clients, or whether you can simply advise your clients how to keep their time reasonably accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Increase the MaxClockSkew property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738468.aspx

Comment: Actually, that is the MaxClock**Skew** - it has nothing to do with "screwing" around with your clock.....

Comment: Haha, *pat my own back for great typo*.